# Reverse a list using ListIterator and skip certain position of character (Java)

Tags: java, list, collections, iterator

I have a task asking for me to print out the given list of strings, skipping every second string. Then, prints the list of strings in reverse order, skipping every second string. All output should be printed on the same line.

For example, if the list of strings is ["a", "b", "c", "d"], the output should be "acdb". If the list of strings is ["a", "b", "c"], the output should be "acca".

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class ListPrintStrings {
public static void printStrings(List<String> strings) {
        // write your code here
        ListIterator<String> stringWithIterator = strings.listIterator(strings.size());
        
        while(stringWithIterator.nextIndex() == 1){
            stringWithIterator.next();
            stringWithIterator.remove();
        }
        for(String s: strings){
            System.out.print(s);
        }
    }
}
```

I have no idea how to reverse the list with a ListIterator and how to return the string together

```
Failures (3):
=> org.junit.ComparisonFailure: The ArrayList had an odd number of elements. Check that your solution can handles an odd number of elements. expected:<a[ceeca]> but was:<a[bcde]>
=> org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<a[cdb]> but was:<a[bcd]>
=> org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<hello[learningisfunjavaworld]> but was:<hello[worldlearningjavaisfun]>
```

These are the error I have. Thank for any help/ hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
public static void printStrings(List<String> strings) {
    ListIterator<String> i = strings.listIterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        System.out.print(i.next());
        if (i.hasNext())
            i.next();
    }
    while (i.hasPrevious()) {
        System.out.print(i.previous());
        if (i.hasPrevious())
            i.previous();
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    printStrings(List.of("a", "b", "c", "d"));
    printStrings(List.of("a", "b", "c"));
}
```

output:

```
acdb
acca
```

Comment: I have error on running this code. `org.junit.ComparisonFailure: The ArrayList had an odd number of elements. Check that your solution can handles an odd number of elements. expected:<[ace]eca> but was:<[]eca>`. `org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[ac]db> but was:<[]db>`, `org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[hellolearningis]funjavaworld> but was:<[]funjavaworld>`. And I should be using `System.out.print` but I can't do it in the code you provided.

Comment: Would you mind to explain what is the hasPervious while loop doing?

Comment: I don't know why such a message is printed. My code doesn't use JUnit or ArrayList.

Comment: At the end of the first while loop, the Iterator pointer is at the end of the string. Each time you execute `previous()` in the second while loop, the Iterator pointer goes back one step. `hasPrevious()` returns false when it reaches the beginning of the string.

Comment: This code does not work properly if you only use the second part: the reverse order. That happens because before you call the `hasPrevious()` you need to move the cursor to the end of the list. That is really important to mention! This is the correct code: `ListIterator<String> i = strings.listIterator(i.size())` Then you can iterate through the list safely with the `listIterator.hasPrevious()`.